# Laravel 5.5 Authorization Policy Not Being Called

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, http-status-code-403, laravel-passport

#### Login Call from Home.vue

```
methods: {
  login: function (e){
   e.preventDefault();
   this.standing = true; // Disables Login Button
   axios.post('/oauth/token', {
    email: this.email, // I verify with email
    password: this.password,
    username: this.username,
    grant_type: 'password',
    client_id: integer_of_client_id,
    client_secret: 'secret_token',
  }).then({response => {
     window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ response.data.access_token;
     // Make call to /api/user
// ...
```

Alrighty so I've double and triple checked my namespacing here and I'm not able to figure out how Laravel is missing this policy I've created:

#### AXIOS CALL on Reply.vue (to delete reply)

`axios.delete('/api/barracks/reply/delete/' + this.reply.id, { id: this.reply.id });`

#### ROUTES/API.PHP

`Route::delete('/barracks/reply/delete/{forumReply}','ForumRepliesController@destroy');`

#### CONTROLLER

```
public function destroy(ForumReply $forumReply)
{

    $this->authorize('destroy', $forumReply);

    $forumReply->delete();

    return response()->json(['Success',204]);
}
```

#### AuthServiceProvider.php

```
// ... Stuff
use App\ForumReply;
use App\Policies\ForumReplyPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        ForumReply::class => ForumReplyPolicy::class
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
        // Passport Stuff
    }
}
```

#### FourmReplyPolicy.php

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\ForumReply;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ForumReplyPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    public function destroy(User $user, ForumReply $forumReply)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Response

I'm getting a 403 response from Laravel and for the life of me I cannot find why.

Comment: Are you certain the current user is authenticated?

Comment: When I return just the `auth()->id()` into the controller method it returns back the correct user ID. :/

Comment: What if you return $user->id === $forumReply->user_id;  (assumning you have a $forumReply->user_id) instead of just returning true in your policy

Comment: Just read it in the docs..it doesn't matter..it should return true or false so disregard my comment.

Comment: What if you dd($forumReply) right before the authorize method in the controller?

Comment: If I dd inside the controller it returns the forum reply object I'm trying to alter.

Comment: So it hits the correct route and route-model binding passes the correct instance, and your policy is returning true, so it doesn't even matter if the current user is authorized...weird..maybe a caching issue?..

Comment: What is really strange is this is running through an SPA using Laravel Passport & VueJS and when I return `Auth::user()` I get back just the ID of the user nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of playing around this I found a temporary workaround that's unfortunately a little ugly.  I've inserted this into the beginning of every controller necessary.

```
$user = \JWTAuth::toUser(\JWTAuth::getToken());
\Auth::loginUsingID($user->id);
```

Then I can use the authorization policy and retrieve authenticated User Info.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody coming to this Thread and using web.php Routes with ->middleware

I had the same issue that the policy wasn't called on this line:

```
    Route::get('/post', 'PostController@index')
        ->middleware('can:index, App\Post');
```

Problem was the space character between index, App.. after removing that it works.

Comment: We should be using the API middleware though for the API requests